# Easy notification of arbitrary events on remote Linux/Unix computer

Tags: linux, unix, monitoring

I am looking for a way to easily define one-time notifications of some events that take place on a Linux box. Events might include things like: `file /tmp/my.lock is unlinked` or `process 666 finished` or, maybe, something more complicated, like `process 'backup.sh' closed file 'backup.tgz' AND process 'backup.sh' exited with return code 0`.

Notifications should be also flexible. Like, `notify 192.168.0.100 via org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify` or `notify me@gmail.com via email`.

Actually, it's something like Nagios, but designed for non-repeating events, with minimal, almost zero cost of task creation. Am I a dreamer? Should I write it myself? Or should I simply use shell scripting?

Answer (score 1):

Nagios can exactly notify the events just one time.
We use it to open tickets.
Just set **notification_interval = 0** (for both service and host) and you'll get the email/sms just once.

Comment: I didn't mean the notification should only be sent once. Rather, the task is used only once, and it's not worth writing yet another `check_file_created` plugin for Nagios.

Comment: But exactly what do you want to monitor? File systems? Logs? Apps?

Comment: As a matter of fact, all of them. I did not simply make up the examples, they are taken from real situations. I might be asking too much, I know :)

Comment: I don't think there's something that sum all the tools to monitor everything. As far as i rember nagios is the most flexible in this situations.

Comment: Yes, but what  I'm looking for should relate to Nagios as 'at' relates to 'cron'.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some more input to the *should I write it myself* question, you could create either a FIFO or flat file to use as a custom log, and add commands to your custom scripts that write important output to that log file. Or alternatively, you could create a simple script that periodically checks the status of important files and processes, and sends its output to that log.

To create the FIFO on the server:

> `mkfifo /var/log/mylog`

To read the logs from the server:

> `ssh user@host "tail -f /var/log/mylog"`

Source these functions into your custom scripts to easily write to the log:

> `function warning { echo -e "\e[33;1m :: \e[0m$@" > /var/log/mylog; };`
>   `function error   { echo -e "\e[31;1m :: \e[0m$@" > /var/log/mylog; };`
>   `function information { echo -e "\e[32;1m :: \e[0m$@" > /var/log/mylog; };`

And then write entries to the log by issuing these commands:

> `information "Some text"`
>   `warning "Some more text"`
>   `error "Some important text"`

You can similarly add a shell function that uses `sendmail` (or similar) to mail you.

Comment: Aha... That looks like a kind of a self-made dedicated message bus... Might be a good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would think a combination of [`inotifywatch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch), `ps`, [`logger`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger) and `syslog` in some custom scripts might do the trick.

Comment: Definitely, it would, especially if combined with `mail` and `expect` :). Unfortunately, these tools will take considerable efforts to set up one simple alert. More than five minutes, that is, which is close to what I consider a threshold.

Comment: @minaev: I was talking about setting up a system to use to create quick, flexible, one-shot alerts. Qualifies under "Should I write it myself?"